# Nginx Reverse Proxy with HTTPS not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, nginx, https, reverse-proxy

I had successfully got the cert of my SSL and now I was trying to implement it into my AWS server with NGINX reserve proxy setup, here is the config file:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  example.com;
    return       301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/cert_chain.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/website.key;
    server_name ~^(?<subdomain>.+)\.example\.com$;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://www.example.com:8888;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $subdomain.example.com;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

If I change the setting to listen to port 80 then it's working fine. I had enabled port 443 in AWS security group and here is the result of `netstat -tulpn | grep 443`:

```
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
```

So it means it's listening to port 443 already right? I also ensured that the nginx was run as root using `ps aux|grep nginx|grep -v grep`:

```
root     11567  0.0  0.3 177080  3060 ?        Ss   09:36   0:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on;
www-data 11568  0.0  0.7 177344  7568 ?        S    09:36   0:00 nginx: worker process
```

I had checked the Nginx error log and it got nothing inside, but when I access my url with https it just showing that it took too long to respond. Anyone able to help? Thank you.

UPDATE

Here is the result of `lsof -i:443`:

```
COMMAND   PID     USER   FD   TYPE  DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
ruby     1067     root    8u  IPv4 2613507      0t0  TCP ip-xxx-xx-xx-xx.us-west-2.compute.internal:49112->xxx-xx-xx-xx:https (ESTABLISHED)
ruby     1067     root   10u  IPv4 2552314      0t0  TCP ip-xxx-xx-xx-xx.us-west-2.compute.internal:43384->s3-us-west-2-r-w.amazonaws.com:https (CLOSE_WAIT)
nginx   12571     root    7u  IPv4 2592465      0t0  TCP *:https (LISTEN)
nginx   12572 www-data    7u  IPv4 2592465      0t0  TCP *:https (LISTEN)
aws     26403     root   14u  IPv4 1903428      0t0  TCP ip-xxx-xx-xx-xx.us-west-2.compute.internal:39960->xxx-xx-xx-xx:https (CLOSE_WAIT)
aws     26403     root   15u  IPv4 2613578      0t0  TCP ip-xxx-xx-xx-xx.us-west-2.compute.internal:55192->xxx-xx-xx-xx:https (CLOSE_WAIT)
```

Comment: seems like there is a process already running on 443 (try `lsof -i:443`). Have you checked the nginx logs?

Comment: @VF_ I had updated the post with the result of this command, it seems nginx is listening to this port?